# Error building pygdal: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3_fixers' and 'use_2to3_exclude_fixers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, gdal

Solution provided below:

Started getting errors when building pygdal on Ubuntu 20.04:

```sh
# Command
python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir pygdal==3.0.4.*
```

produces the following output

```
Collecting pygdal==3.0.4.*
  Downloading pygdal-3.0.4.6.tar.gz (458 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 458 kB 3.7 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-we7e68ge/pygdal/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-we7e68ge/pygdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-we7e68ge/pygdal/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-we7e68ge/pygdal/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3_fixers'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3_exclude_fixers'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in pygdal setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The steps to reproduce the error are:

```sh
# Commands to run inside of running Ubuntu 20.04 docker instance
apt update
# install python3.8 and link python3 to this version - these next 2 steps may not be needed for your scenario
apt install -y python3.8
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
# done installing python3.8
apt install -y python3-pip
apt-get install -y python3-gdal gdal-bin libgdal-dev gcc g++ python3.8-dev git
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir setuptools==58.0.4
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir numpy wheel requests
python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir pygdal==3.0.4.*
```

The solution is to install an older version of setuptools. Specifying version 58.0.2 and earlier resulted in a successful build. I only went back to 58.0.0 for this issue, but this is the first time I've seen this issue so earlier versions should work as well.

```sh
# Replace the above installation of setuptools with the following
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir setuptools==58.0.2
```

Comment: The GitHub issue for this can be found at https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2781

Comment: We're seeing this too, all of a sudden.  Carefully looking at our build infra to see what changed but nothing has popped out at me yet after a careful look.

Comment: Suggestion, @chrissc: add your answer (from the body of the question) as an answer to make it easier to parse.

Thanks for tracking this down, you saved our bacon.

Answer (score 18):

For installing GDAL version 3.0.4. In my case, I've downgrading the setuptools from 58.2.0 to 57.5.0 version worked.
Using the command:

```
pip3 install setuptools==57.5.0
```

Comment: This worked for me for GDAL 3.0.0.

Comment: For me, this happened when installing using Poetry, since Poetry versions `<1.2` depend on a `setuptools` greater than `57.5.0`, breaking GDAL build (version 3.2.2 in my case). Doing this `pip install` before the `poetry install` works and fixes this error.

Comment: If you still have problems, try to also use an old pip, like `pip install pip==20.0.2`

Comment: I have updated `wheel`, its works fine

Comment: Omg it worked and nothing else did, thanks! `Successfully installed GDAL-3.2.2`

Answer (score 8):

Replace the above installation of setuptools with the following

```sh
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir setuptools==58.0.2
```

depending upon which version of pygdal you are using, you may need to use an earlier version of setuptools

Comment: Thanks. For my `setuptools==58.0` did it

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to install the python GDAL version which is the same as the distribution GDAL.
for Ubuntu:

```
gadi@gadi:$ dpkg-query --list |grep gdal
ii  gdal-bin                                      3.4.1+dfsg-1build4                      amd64        Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
```

and then

```
pip install GDAL==3.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin libgdal-dev
```

then

```
pip install GDAL==3.4.1
```