# Trying to install GDAL on Ubuntu 20: error in GDAL setup command: use_2to3 is invalid

Tags: python, pip, gdal

I'm trying to install GDAL using this command:

`pip install GDAL==3.0.4`

but I'm getting this below:

[image]

I'm using `pip install GDAL==3.0.4` instead of `pip install GDAL` (that would install the current latest version 3.6.2) because looks like I have installed the version `3.0.4` of `libgdal-dev`:

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: what version do you get when you run `gdalinfo --version`?

Comment: @val GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28

Comment: Maybe it's related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123406/error-building-pygdal-unknown-distribution-option-use-2to3-fixers-and-use-2)? Otherwise, I'd really recommend using `conda`/`mamba` to install packages with complex dependencies like `gdal`